# uploading large file to GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

I want to upload whole of the Dbpedia data set to the GraphDB. I have installed am using Docker container and have run it successfully. Now the problem is, I am unable to upload the .nt files because the maximum size of the file allowed is 200 MB. Can anybody help?

Comment: I have currently exactly the same problem as you described. Did you find a solution for this question?

Comment: Create a docker image first, then try this command. sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:7200:7200 -v /home/laptop/Downloads/de/downloads:/home/laptop/Downloads/de/downloads --name graphdb -e "GDB_JAVA_OPTS= -Dgraphdb.workbench.importDirectory=/home/laptop/Downloads/de/downloads" ontotext/graphdb:9.0.0-free (here is the version of your graphdb image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max size is governed by the graphdb.workbench.maxUploadSize property. You can change it in your server settings by setting a new value for it (in bytes).

Comment: A detailed explanation is highly appreciated...

Comment: This explanations seems sufficient enough

Answer (score 2):

You can surpass the limit by using Import -> Server files. You can change the directory of the server files by passing -Dgraphdb.workbench.importDirectory=path_to_directory when starting GraphDB.