# Upload a massive rdf file into GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

I have a quite big rdf file (3.5Gb) and want to import it into graphDB, but because of the limit in there (200MB), I can't do that. I saw a similar post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988990/uploading-large-file-to-graphdb), but the explanation is not detailed enough to be followed. Any solution or detailed explanation of steps to be able to load a large rdf file into graphDB?

Answer (score 3):

If you can do it offline, use their [importrdf](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.4/cli-importrdf.html?highlight=preload) tool. It's specifically designed for loading large datasets.

If you need GraphDB to remain online, then you need to upload it as a [Server File](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.4/loading-data-using-the-workbench.html#importing-server-files). The tldr is that you need to place your RDF in GraphDB's server file directory (whatever the `graphdb.workbench.importDirectory` points to). Once there, it will appear in the Workbench and you can import it via the UI.

The documentation linked should explain it all, if there's anything that doesn't make sense edit your post about what you've tried, and where you're hitting a snag.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I did to import that. I just needed to create a folder with the name *graphdb-import* in my GraphDB's server file directory (for me on Mac it was in *~/users/my_userName/*), and then upload the rdf file there. So, once you restart the Graphdb workbench, you should see the rdf file name under the server files. Finally, when you provide the URI of the rdf file, you can successfully import it there.